# Modifying tab bar items in parent view controller

Tags: ios, ios5, uitabbarcontroller, xcode4.2

Is it possible to modify tab bar items in the parent view controller during prepareForSegue? Basically, I'm trying to insert logic in the parent controller where one of 2 possible tab bar items may be removed upon segue.

I've tried something along the lines of:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"identifierOfInterest"]) {
        UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)segue.destinationViewController;

        // Attempt 1
        NSMutableArray *items = [[tabBarController.tabBar items] mutableCopy];
        [items removeObjectAtIndex:1];
        [tabBarController.tabBar setItems:items animated:YES];

        // Attempt 2
        NSMutableArray *items = [[tabBarController viewControllers] mutableCopy];
        [items removeObjectAtIndex:1];
        [tabBarController setViewControllers:items];
    }
}
```

Unfortunately both messages crash the app with the following errors:

Attempt 1:

```
Directly modifying a tab bar managed by a tab bar controller is not allowed.
```

Attempt 2:

```
[UITabBarItem parentViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I'm using Xcode 4.2, iOS 5 with the UI Tab Bar Controller being a storyboard object, so there are no outlets to the tab bar or anything.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Typically in a TabBar application, the AppDelegate owns (or has a reference to) the tab bar controller, since it is the "main" view controller.  You cannot seque to a tab bar view controller, or at least you SHOULD not.  If you need to have the application's tab bar controller perform some action, send a message to the App Delegate instance, which should have a reference to the Tab Bar Controller, to perform the work.

i.e.

```
//In View Controller handling seque
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] performSelector:@selector(doTabBarWork:) withObject:data];
}

//In the App delegate
-(void)doTabBarWork:(id)data
{
    //The "mainTabBarController" instance needs to already be set
    NSMutableArray *viewControllers =  [[self.mainTabBarController viewControllers] mutableCopy];
    [viewControllers removeLastObject];
    [self.mainTabBarController setViewControllers:viewControllers animated:YES];
}
```